# this.textSize is not a function

Tags: vue.js, d3.js, promise

I have this error **:**

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: this.textSize is not a function

for `this.textSize` if I just put `textSize` it tells me that it is not defined.

while they are in the same file one below the other

```
textSize(text, classname="textDefault") {
        /* Get the size of the given text rendered in pixels.
        text : string
        output : dict
        */
        if (!d3) return;
        let container = d3.select("body")
            .append("svg");
        container.append("text")
            .attr("class", classname)
            .attr("x", -99999)
            .attr("y", -99999)
            .text(text);
        let size = container.node().getBBox();
        container.remove();
        return { "width": size.width, "height": size.height };
    },
    getYTickNumberWidth(dataValues, tickLabelFormat) {
        /* Get width for y tick number labels.
        dataValues : list/float
        tickLabelFormat : function
        output : float
        */

        return d3.max(dataValues.map(
            function(d) {
                console.log(this.textSize())
                let size = this.textSize(tickLabelFormat(d));
                return size.width;
            }
        ));
    },
```

Comment: Can you try to use arrow function as it refers to the global scope. Instead of `function(d)` try `d =>`

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you are using a function instead of an arrow function.
try this:

```
    getYTickNumberWidth(dataValues, tickLabelFormat) {
    /* Get width for y tick number labels.
    dataValues : list/float
    tickLabelFormat : function
    output : float
    */

    return d3.max(dataValues.map(
        (d) => {
            console.log(this.textSize())
            let size = this.textSize(tickLabelFormat(d));
            return size.width;
        }
    ));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here issue is with the scope of `this`. As you are using [regular function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions) inside `map` which contains it's own `this` and trying to access `textSize` in it's own scope.

Hence, You have to use arrow function in which the value of `this` remains the same throughout the lifecycle of the function and is always bound to the value of `this` in the closest non-arrow parent function.

Demo **:**

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    items: []
  },
  methods: {
    textSize(item) {
        this.items.push(item)
    },
    getYTickNumberWidth() {
      this.items = [];
        /* [1, 2, 3].map(function(item) {   // ❌
                this.textSize(item);
              }); */
      
      [1, 2, 3].map((item) => {    // ✅
        this.textSize(item);
      });
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <button @click="getYTickNumberWidth">
  Get Items
  </button>
  <pre>{{ items }}</pre>
</div>
```